# JQuery: $(this).text('some_text'); is causing my link to have a border

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('a.btn-slide').toggle(function() {
    $("#SliderDIV").slideDown("fast");
    $(this).text('Hide/Show');
});
```

Only in Firefox, when I click the a href link to hide/show the DIV, Firefox display a dotted border around the href link (which I don't understand why and it shouldn't be).

However, in IE and Chrome, when I toggle the link - it does not create this strange border around the link.

Comment: Are you talking about the focus rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thus, you want to get rid of the [dotted outline](http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/)?

Just do

```
a {
   outline: none;
}
```

This however impacts users with keyboard navigation. They won't be able anymore to figure which link they've tabbed now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the outline property. It is generally an annoying thing. you can set it off in your master stylesheet like this:

```
* {outline:none;}
```

Comment: eek, this will remove outlines on every element.. this could create unwanted problems - since the issue at hand is simply active links, it might be better to restrict this to the active link..

Comment: can you explain what kind of problem it causes?

Comment: This is a bad idea.  The outline tells you what element is focused, and it's a very important usability feature.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are talking about the dotting border that appears after a link is clicked.. it is annoying haha but here is what I've used in the past to fix it

http://sonspring.com/journal/removing-dotted-links

```
a:active {
  outline: none;
}
```

This way you are being specific to your links, and avoiding any issues with other css elements.

Answer (score 0):

Add `outline: none !important` to the element's CSS.

Comment: ! important should be reserved for disabled users so they can over ride the your css settings. there is always a way in the inheritance hierarchy to avoid using !important